# How to create dummy list dynamically by giving count as a input in terraform

Tags: terraform

My requirement is to create a list in terraform dynamically using count as an input
for example if count is 3 I want to create a dynamic dummy list like ["dummyval","dummyval","dummyval"]

Answer (score 1):

```
locals {
  mylist = [for i in range(3) : "dummyval"]
}
```